# Windows Phone 8.1 Store App Error While Getting MusicLibrary (Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component)

Tags: c#, windows-phone, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml, windows-phone-8.1

While trying to get the MusicLibrary on WP 8.1 app, the following error occurs. I use the below method. This was working fine for the last few weeks and suddenly it gave this error:

> Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component
>   [System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException] = {System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80004005): Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.}

**Not Working**

```
static IReadOnlyList<StorageFile> files;
files = await KnownFolders.MusicLibrary.GetFilesAsync(CommonFileQuery.OrderByName);
```

However the code works without the CommonFileQuery. But it only gets the files in the root.

**Working**

```
static IReadOnlyList<StorageFile> files;
files = await KnownFolders.MusicLibrary.GetFilesAsync();
```

This happened right after updating the Xbox Music app. Does anyone know what's wrong?

Comment: Are you tesing in on device/emulator? Does it have SD card? Can you check if you add a capability *removable device*, if the error still occurs?

Comment: I'm testing on a Device.It doesn't have a SD card.Yes. All capabilities are added.I tried soft resetting the device as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue was solved by hard resetting the device (Lumia 1520). After resetting Xbox Music returned to the older version(Initial version for 8.1). Maybe that could be the fix. Anyway, the cause of this error is unknown.

Answer (score 1):

there's a bug in the apis that use the CommonXXXQuery queries.

See here :
[OrderByName error](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-us/c2735ff6-7f5f-42e9-943c-d8bd41d41548/knownfoldersmusiclibrarygetfilesasynccommonfilequeryorderbyname-fails-with-hresult-efail-on?forum=wpdevelop)

and here:
[GroupByArtist/GroupByAlbum error](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-us/482ab229-8ca3-412f-8a82-2cc66f12eea7/comexception-hresult-efail-when-using?forum=wpdevelop)

For files, do not use OrderByName but use

musicLibrary.GetFoldersAsync(), then on the folder GetFilesAsync() and recurse on subfolders.

For artists/ albums grouping, do not use the queries as well. I haven't found a workaround so far because since I can't reproduce this errors on my devices, I can only guess and so far no success.

EDIT: after re-reading you post "This happened right after updating the Xbox Music app". This is the key here. No words from MS, but my guess is that the xbox music app has access to apis to index the audio files but at some point the indexing gets corrupted.

Comment: I solved the issue by hard resetting my device(1520). I have no idea what was wrong. But, after resetting Xbox Music returned to the older version(Initial version for 8.1). Maybe that could be the fix. I did not update the app after the reset.

Comment: well what happens when you start getting reports from your app users about this issue ? are you going to ask them to hard reset their phone ?

Comment: I checked with several devices before hard resetting. Code worked fine on them.Issue seemed to be with the device. So, had no option. And no one was able to provide a solution either. Since resetting has nothing to do with my code, I guess this is an isolated issue for my device.